# What happens to existing beta testers when I remove the beta testing program from my app?

Tags: google-play

We had an app on play store for a while on beta and we didn't go to production. When we finally released production version after a year or so, we had a ton of existing users still on the beta program. We want to move those users to the production version of the app and remove the beta program entirely. How to do this?

I have seen the option of removing the beta testing program. If I do so, what happens to existing users? Do they get the new prod update or they have to download the app manually again? How do I seamlessly transition them to the production version of the app without having them to download the app again/have automatic updates working as is?